# Search and extract results from an array based on an entry keyword in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I would like to compare an Array to an element and extract those data in the another Array 
Here is an example of data i'm working with:

```
Array = [{:id=>3, :keyword=>"happy", :Date=>"01/02/2016"},
         {:id=>4, :keyword=>"happy", :Date=>"01/02/2016"} ... ]
```

for example i want the first keyword happy to search the same array ,extract if there's any similar words and put them inside another array here is what i'm looking for an end result:

```
Results = [{:keyword=>happy, :match =>{ 
           {:id=>3, :keyword=>"happy", :Date=>"01/02/2016"}... }]
```

Here is the first part of the code :

```
 def relationship(file)
    data     = open_data(file)
    parsed   = JSON.parse(data)
    keywords = []
    i = 0
    parsed.each do |word|
    keywords << { id: i += 1 , keyword: word['keyword'].downcase, Date:     word['Date'] }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def search_keyword(keyword)
    hash = [
        {:id=>1, :keyword=>"happy", :Date=>"01/02/2015"},
        {:id=>2, :keyword=>"sad", :Date=>"01/02/2016"},
        {:id=>3, :keyword=>"fine", :Date=>"01/02/2017"},
        {:id=>4, :keyword=>"happy", :Date=>"01/02/2018"}
    ]
    keywords = []
    hash.each do |key|
        if key[:keyword] == keyword
            keywords << key
        end
    end
    keywords
    #{:keyword=> keyword, :match=> keywords}
end

search_keyword('fine')
#search_keyword('sad')
```

You could group the match elements by key (:match) then get the result with a single hash lookup.

Comment: Thank you , but ` key[:keyword].include?(keyword)`  works better for multiple keywords match

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea that could help you with your situation using enumerable and index:

**array to be search:**

```
array = [
        {:id=>3, :keyword=>"happy", :Date=>"01/02/2016"},
        {:id=>4, :keyword=>"happy", :Date=>"01/02/2016"},
        {:id=>1, :keyword=>"happy", :Date=>"01/02/2015"},
        {:id=>2, :keyword=>"sad",   :Date=>"01/02/2016"},
        {:id=>30, :keyword=>"fine", :Date=>"01/02/2017"},
        {:id=>41, :keyword=>"happy", :Date=>"01/02/2018"}
  ]
```

**method search:**
store all element matching the term in the array.

```
def search(term, array)
    array = []
    array << {keyword: "#{term}", match: []}
    arr.select { |element| array.first[:match] << element if element[:keyword].index(term) }
    array
end
```

**Testing:**

```
  p search('sa', array)
  # => [{:keyword=>"sa", :match=>[{:id=>2, :keyword=>"sad", :Date=>"01/02/2016"}, {:id=>21, :keyword=>"sad", :Date=>"01/02/2016"}]}]
```

hope that will get you goin!